# Implementing Parallax scrolling with fixed header [Windows Phone]

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone

I'm trying to implement something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zem52.gif) layout, a fixed header parallax scrolling view. In my case it's not a thin header resembling LongListSelector's fixed header, it's more like a complex pivot control reserving more space.

I've found and tried to work with [this](http://y2bd.me/blog/2014/03/18/creating-a-parallax-scrolling-effect-on-windows-phone/) example but I couldn't manage to get it working with a fixed header.

Any ideas that could be useful would be appreciated!

Comment: What's not working? The example seems to be pretty appropriate.

Comment: _I couldn't manage to get it working with a fixed header._ 
In the given example there's a single scrollable area, everything goes on top of the background image. Imagine I want the title/subtitle part of it to be a header that is fixed in the upper most part of the screen.

Comment: At the bottom of that post is a link to a possible solution you are looking for: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27772.windows-phone-how-to-keep-a-ui-element-in-view-when-scrolling-a-page-in-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: thanks for sharing, @Depechie. Working on it..

Comment: @Depechie, can you post this as an answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete post to a possible guide on how to solve this can be found here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27772.windows-phone-how-to-keep-a-ui-element-in-view-when-scrolling-a-page-in-windows-phone.aspx

TL;DR

In short, if you need to scroll and keep an item static ( so that it will not scroll out of visible window ), you'll need to hook into the `ValueChanged` event of the `ScrollBar` inside a `ScrollViewer`.
With that in place you can inspect the value that is returned and validate it to see if the static object needs to be animated too - or not.
You validate it against another element on the screen that is your 'top element' or against the top or bottom of the screen itself.

Demo video of the solution : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsnQCfVUTTA